# complexity of linear programming

Tags: linear-programming, computational-complexity

I am analyzing the computational complexity of an algorithm that includes as a step the solution of a linear subproblem of n variables and n constraints.

The linear subproblem  can be solved by the karmarkar's interior point method. In this case the complexity of this step is $O(n^{3}L)$, where $L$ is the bit size.

I have two questions:

1. Why is the size of bit included in the complexity of karmarkar's method? (Could one write just $O(n^{3})$?)

2.Knowing that the complexity of the other steps of my algorithm is of $O(n)$, what is the total time complexity of the algorithm? Is it $O(n^{3})$?

Comment: For 2) : $O(n^3)+O(n) = O(n^3)$, indeed.

Comment: For 1): did you read the remarks on $L$ in "A new polynomial-time algorithm for linear programming" by Karmarkar? For 2): that depends if the linear program is nested (i.e., executed repeatedly or just once).

Comment: @LinAlg I read this remark where they claim the importance of $L$, but if I understand correctly it is not  wrong if we remove it as in the Gauss method!! Is it correct?? For 2: the execution is repeated until convergence, but I want to analyse the complexity of one iteration.

Comment: @Kuifje Thanks.

Comment: Karmarkar algorithm should take $n^{3.5}$ time. The state-of-the-art algorithm takes current matrix multiplication time ($n^{\omega}$, where $\omega \approx 2.373$) due to Cohen, Lee, Song  STOC19. https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07896